Is it possible to stop latex (xelatex) after rendering just one page of output?
Is it possible to stop Latex after rendering just one page of output?
I'm attempting to do presentation slides in Emacs Orgmode with subsequent export to Latex & PDF. This way I believe I could have a quick preview and see problems like page boundaries overrun (my slides are heavy-ish on graphics, so I'd like to not reprocess the whole every time, and being slides, my pages aren't dependent on each other for text flowing).
Right now I see only a variant of deliberately inserting an error at the page/slide intended lower boundary and running Latex with -halt-on-error, which seems very inelegant.
Solutions specific to XeLaTex are welcome.
My MWE uses relsize, if that's okay. I'd like the latex run to stop shortly after the line with '6':
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\renewcommand\RSlargest{100pt}
\begin{document}
\relsize{10}
1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

\end{document}


LaTeX ignores everything behind the first \end{document}.

Outside emacs' orgmode, AucTeX with previewmode is very nice to get a preview of regions.

Maybe versions. Also beamer allows to name slides and include only the slides mentioned in a provided list. However, can you give a minimal example before & after export?

Thank you for your suggestions, guys. Those aren't quite relevant to the issue, though. If I knew reliably where the page ends I'd just make a short macro previewing just the necessary part (region in orgmode terms). However, there may be graphics on the page, or newlines, etc., so the page ending just isn't known.

\usepackage[1]{pagesel} would be the easiest.

@Marijn: Yes, that seems to be it, thank you very much! Interestingly, this page didn't crop once, neither in search engine nor in SE suggestions.
